# Abstract Class Hierarchy and Access Violation

Tags: c++

The background to this is that I am attempting to re-factor a complex C++ application. I have put together the code below as a trimmed down version of the code I am working with (cutting out the irrelevent methods etc.). I am probably doing something stupid as I have not touched C++ in years, but I can see what...

I have the following classes

**message_sink.h:**

```
class IMessageSink
{
public:
    virtual ~IMessageSink() { };
    virtual void process(const Message& msg) = 0;
};
```

with the following base class

**model_base.h:**

```
class Model : public virtual IMessageSink
{
public:
   Model(Tag a);

   virtual Model* makeA(Tag a) = 0;
   void reset();

private:
   friend class EM;

   const Tag _a;
   virtual void calculate(double lambda) = 0;
};
```

where **model_base.cpp** is

```
Model::Model(Tag a) : _a(a) { }

void Model::reset()
{
   // ... some implementation
}

void Model::process(const Message msg)
{
    // ... some implementation
}
```

I then have the following classes inheriting from the base class

**model_m0.h:**

```
class ModelM0 : public virtual Model
{
public:
    ModelM0(Tag a);        
    ModelM0* make(Tag a);

private:
    void calculate(double lambda);
};
```

**model_m0.cpp:**

```
ModelM0::ModelM0(Tag a) : Model(a) { }

ModelM0* ModelM0::make(Tag a)
{
   ModelM0* m = new ModelM0(a);
   m->reset();
   return m;
}

void ModelM0::calculate(double lambda)
{
    // Some code...
}
```

But here is where the problems lies, I have another class called `ModelM0Holder` and this is defined as

**model_m0_holder.h:**

```
class ModelM0Holder : public IMessageSink
{
public:
    static ModelM0Holder* make(Tag a)
    {
        return new ModelM0Holder(a);
    }
    ModelM0Holder(Tag a);
    ~ModelM0Holder();
    void process(const Message& msg);

private:
    ModelM0* getModel(int line);
};
```

and **model_m0_holder.cpp:** is

```
ModelM0Holder::ModelM0Holder(Tag a) : _a(a) { } 

ModelM0Holder::~ModelM0Holder()
{
    // ... some implementation
}

void ModelM0Holder::process(const Message& msg)
{
    // ... some implementation
}

ModelM0* ModelM0Holder::getModel(int ag)
{
    ModelM0* m;
    m = m->make(_a); // Access Violation Exception.
    // ... 
}
```

When I call `ModelM0Holder::getModel` I get an `AccessViolationException`, I can't call this function, why?

Thanks very much for your time.

Comment: You've cut out too much relevant information to be sure.  But `ModeM0::getModel()` does not seem to do anything to prevent dereferencing `i`, even if `i` is an end iterator.   It also does not initialise `m` before dereferencing it.  Those both cause undefined behaviour.    Also, `IMessageSink::process()` accepts an argument by reference, but `Model::process()` accepts argument by value - which means it hides rather than overrides the inherited version.

Comment: You are using unitialized `m` in call to `m->makeA()`. Should probably be a static method, so `ModelM0::makeA()`, but then it can not be virtual. Same for `makeB`.

Comment: Peter makes some valid points, these things might not individually be your problem, but together that might do something like what you are seeing

Comment: Thanks for your time guys, most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do `m->` when `m` is unitialized. That will access a random memory location (and cause a dump).

If I understand the intention of your code correctly, you can make `makeA` and `makeB` static.

```
class ModelM0 : public virtual Model
{
public:
    . . .    
    static ModelM0* makeA(Tag newObsTag);
    static ModelM0* makeB(Tag newObsTag);
    . . .    
};
```

Then change `getModel` to look like this:

```
    ModelM0* m;

    if (_period == tau::PERIOD_A)
        m = ModelM0::makeA(_newObsTag);
    else
        m = ModelM0::makeB(_newObsTag);
```

Comment: I had the `makeA` and `makeB` static before the refactor, I have just tried to go overboard. This is clearly the problem - never code hungover...

Answer (score 3):

```
ModelM0* m;

if (_period == tau::PERIOD_A)
    m = m->makeA(_newObsTag); // Access Violation Exception.
else
    m = m->makeB(_newObsTag);
```

You are attempting to dereference uninitialized pointer `m`. This is an undefined behavior. It is difficult to tell how exactly this should be fixed without knowing your project details. Perhaps some kind of factory should be used instead.